# How to add breakpoints to Runnable classes

Tags: java, multithreading, intellij-idea

My `while(true)` is only running once, so I'm trying to add breakpoints to see what's going on, but they never seem to be reached within my `run()`.  I'm using IntelliJ.  In the debugger there's a "Threads" tab.  Do I need to do something in that tab like select the right thread in order for my breakpoint to be reached?  I also see thread names and am wondering how I can find the right thread in this list.

```
public class MyClass extends ServerWorkflowProcess<OtherClass> {

    private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    ...

    @Override
    public void bootup() {
        logger.info("Booting up: " + this);

        BackgroundProcess backgroundImpositioner = new BackgroundProcess(this.getCollection());
        executorService.submit(backgroundImpositioner);
    }

    @Override
    public void shutdown() {
        executorService.shutdown();
    }
}
```

**Background process**

```
public class BackgroundProcess implements Runnable {

    protected volatile Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(BackgroundImpositioner.class.getName());

    Collection<ImpositionWorkstation> impositionWorkstations;

    public BackgroundImpositioner(Collection<ImpositionWorkstation> impositionWorkstation) {
        this.impositionWorkstations = impositionWorkstation;
    }

    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            logger.info("looping");
            for (ImpositionWorkstation workstation : impositionWorkstations) {
                if (workstation.canAcceptWork()) {

                    //go do work in another thread so we're not blocking this
                    workstation.getWorkFromQueue();
                    try {
                        workstation.doWork();
                    } catch (ImpositionException e) {
                        logger.severe(e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                logger.severe("Background impositioner was interrupted");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Side note: the console shows "looping", so I know it gets executed once.  The breakpoint never gets hit and it doesn't execute more than once.

Comment: In `BackgroundProcess = new BackgroundProcess(this.getCollection());`, do you mean `BackgroundProcess backgroundImpositioner = new BackgroundProcess(this.getCollection());`?

Comment: it's more likely that the line of code you set the breakpoint on doesn't get executed

Comment: Are you sure it runs even once? Put a try { ... } catch(Throwable ex) { ex.printStackTrace();} around everything in the run method.

Comment: @Stroboskop Doesn't catch anything

Comment: @svz But why wouldn't it is what I'm struggling to see

Comment: @Webnet, you should probably add an SSCCE cause it's hard to tell what's wrong in the code you provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happened to me once that i couldn't make Intellij Idea stop in breakpoints. Basically the problem is that once a thread is stopped in a breakpoint the others won't stop.

There is a setting in the breakpoints properties dialog that prevents this.

Right click on a breakpoint and select 'View Breakpoints'.

On the dialog select a breakpoint.

You will notice on the right of suspend checkbox 2 radio buttons: **All** and **Thread**. Select **All**. Aditionally you can make that the default (**Make Default** button on the right). The default value will be used for any new breakpoints you add. The old ones need to be changed manually.

**EDIT**
Additional info on the Intellij help site: [Breakpoint options](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/breakpoints-2.html#d308158e402)

[image: breakpoint dialog]

Comment: @Webnet i added the link to the idea help site where they explain how/when the debugger won't stop. My solution was to select all. It might be the other way around if the problem is with the ide.

Answer (score 0):

Don’t let exceptions slip through silently. Use the `Future` returned by the `submit` method.

```
Future<?> f=executorService.submit(backgroundImpositioner);
try {
  f.get();
} catch(Exception ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Then you know more.

The code above is just for finding your actual problem. For production environments you wouldn’t wait for completion but rather log the exception when it occurred, e.g.:

```
executorService.execute(new FutureTask<Object>(backgroundImpositioner, null)
{
  @Override
  protected void done() {
    if(!isCancelled()) try {
      get();
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
      throw new AssertionError("on completed task", ex);
    } catch(ExecutionException ex) {
      logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "in background task", ex.getCause());
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: There’s not enough information about the context for us to find the reason. If your loop is not terminated by an exception, there’s only one other possibility why it is not going into a second iteration: it is still executing the first one. But in this case your debug tool can easily tell you where the thread is hanging…

Comment: That's where I'm struggling, because it's not picking up on any breakpoints and there's no exceptions or anything in the console to indicate it's busy.

Comment: I don’t know much about `IntelliJ` but other debuggers allow you to stop a running thread at any time, regardless of break points. Or you can use tools like `JVisualVM` to get a thread dump for a running application (which can be started from `IntelliJ`)—that’s not even considered a debugging operation (i.e. works even with Java programs not running in Debug mode).

Answer (score 0):

For a reason beyond me, I was not able to breakpoint the `while(true)` line, but was able to drop breakpoints elsewhere within the `run()`.

Comment: That’s not surprising. The `while(true)` statement does not contain any code to stop at. It creates an unconditional loop so there’s no code evaluating a condition. The resulting behavior depends on how the compiler treats this situation when creating line debugging information, and how the debugger implements inserting/setting a breakpoint. Some debuggers automatically move the breakpoint to the next line/instruction that allows a break point, others don’t.

Answer (score 0):

If there's no exception thrown inside the run method, i can only assume that one of the calls never returns.

Can you put output statements after every single call to see how far you get?
I guess either `workstation.canAcceptWork()` or `workstation.doWork()` is the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

I've met a similar problem that IntelliJ never hits my breakpoint in the run() method of a Runnable class. I found that the only position for the breakpoint to be hit is at the line of `public void run() {`.